# Making sympy function with 2 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module, sympy

I´m trying to do a piecewise function with sympy, but I can´t. It doesn´t the piecewise function.
I want a **simple funtion** when (x,y) != (0,0) and **a** when (x,y) = (0,0)
Can someone help me ?

Thank you so much

I tried this code:

```
f_exp = sp.Piecewise((((x*y)*(x**2 - y**2)) / (x**2 + y**2), (x,y) != (0,0)), (a, (x,y) == (0,0)))
f = sp.Lambda((x,y), f_exp) # Creamos la función
display(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write `(x,y) != (0,0)` because Python intercept that codes before Sympy, and it performs the comparison: in this case, clearly the tuple `(x, y)` is different from `(0, 0)`.

Hence, you'd have to manually construct the relationship. Here are two ways to achieve it:

```py
f_exp = Piecewise((((x*y)*(x**2 - y**2)) / (x**2 + y**2), And(Ne(x, 0), Ne(y, 0))), (a, True))
f_exp = Piecewise((a, Eq(x, 0) & Eq(y, 0)), (((x*y)*(x**2 - y**2)) / (x**2 + y**2), True))
```

Comment: Any of that examples work. It says Eq is not defined, Ne is not defined. How can I define them ?

Comment: Since you used `import sympy as sp`, you'd have to use `sp.Eq` or `sp.Ne` or `sp.And`, and so on